# Styling asp.net controls

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm hoping someone can help me with this.

When I'm styling html components say all divs on the page I would add a CSS like:

```
div
{
  background-color:Red;
}
```

which works fine. However when it come to styling an asp.net control say a button I try:

```
button
{
  background-color:Red;
}
```

but this doesn't work. Could someone please tell me how you style these creatures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An asp.net button is actually an `input` element. So to style it you would use:

```
input { background-color: red; }
```

But that would style all input elements (text boxes, button, radio buttons, check boxes). To target just buttons you can use some CSS3:

```
input[type=button] { background-color: red; }
```

Or, you can just give all the buttons you want to style a class and do it that way:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="red-button" />

.red-button { background-color: red; }
```